# How is the union bound applied in this proof?

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning

From Understanding Machine Learning: From theory to algorithms:

How explicitly is the union bound used in the proof of this theorem to get the result in the red box below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let your events be $A_n = \{ |L_D(h) - L_S(h)| < \epsilon_n$ holds for all $h \in \mathcal{H}_n \}$.

$P(A_n^c) < \delta_n $ as per the previous paragraph, where I am using $c$ to denote complement. Now, we are looking for the event that all $A_n$'s happen, i.e. for the $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_n) = 1 - P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_n^c)$. Now, using union bound on that last term we get $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_n^c) \leq \sum_i P(A_i^c) \leq \sum_i \delta_i$, so $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_n)$ is at least $1 - \sum_i \delta_i$.

---

Adding the elements of the set as per OPs request: the theorem says that the space we are working in is $\Omega = \mathcal{D}^n$, and we pick some $S$ in it. So, more formally, we have 
$A_n = \{ S \in \mathcal{D}^n: |L_D(h) - L_S(h)| < \epsilon_n$ holds for all $h \in \mathcal{H}_n \}$.

Comment: I'm a little confused on your notation of $A_n$, what is an element of that set?

Comment: What does $S \in D^n$ mean?  I've never seen the notation of a set of samples being an element of a distribution.  The notation $S \text{~} D^n$ is what is in the book and means the $n$ elements of the set $S$ are chosen according to distribution $D$.

Comment: And what do you mean by $\Omega = D^n$?  Because to me that reads: the sample space is the distribution function that maps events from a sample space to $[0,1]$.

Comment: That is what I thought but it is pretty hard to try to infer the content of a book from one screenshot... Either way, then the sample space is whatever domain $S$ belongs to to the $n$. If you upload the relevant screenshots for the definitions it might be easier for people to help you.